# Optimize chunkshape parameter of pytables/HDF5 for reading entire column

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

I'm trying to improve performance of my pytables/HDF5 code by specifying the `chunkshape` when creating a table.  I can't figure out what the real dimensions or format of the `chunkshape` parameter.  I can see from the code that I it ultimately ends up as a tuple with a single element.

Is this single element supposed to be the number of rows, bytes, or what?

My specific issue is I have existing code that creates an HDF5 table with 20 columns.  I would like to change the chunks of the table so that each column is stored contiguously on disk.  Thus, optimizing for reading entire columns out at a single time.

I tried just setting the chunkshape to 20 (number of columns), but this dramatically decreased the performance of reading an entire column.  Should the chunk shape be set to the width (in bytes) of a single row?

I would just like to know what the chunkshape should be if:

1. I want to read an entire column as fast as possible.
2. I know exactly how many columns are in the table.
3. I cannot just simply change the table to have the existing rows as columns and vice-versa for backwards-compatibility reasons.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to ask this question to the PyTables mailing list. You can get a really great support there.

Answer (score 4):

The `chunkshape` in `PyTables` specifies the number of elements per row and column that should be stored contiguously on disk (that's the reason why it is a tuple).

So, for instance if your dataset is 10,000 x 20  (10,000 rows, 20 columns) and you always access  a single column at a time , then each chunk should contain as much of a column as possible, given your best  chunk size (see [here](http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/optimization.html) for more details).

If you know how many rows you will have and they are not that huge you could specify a chunkshape of `(10.000,1)` (or fewer rows). So if you access all 20 columns it will take 20 accesses.

Comment: I see that it is a tuple that corresponds to rows and columns.  This is consistent with the documentation of HDF5 and `chunksize`.  However, pytables doesn't really allow a 2-tuple (row and column) to be set through this parameter.  I get an error complaining about 'rank must be 1' when trying to set the `chunkshape` to something like (1, 20).  Why is this parameter a `chunkshape` if it only uses the first element of the tuple I pass it?  How would I use `chunkshape` to optimize reading entire columns in as few disk accesses as possible?

Comment: that's weird because according to [this](http://www.pytables.org/trac-bck/browser/PyTablesPro/trunk/bench/chunkshape-bench.py?rev=3895) a normal tuple should work. You could also try to specify the `expectedrows` parameter and let PyTables calculate the optimal  `chunkshape` and then output it and see if it works for you.

Comment: I'll look into `expectedrows`.  In the meantime, here is the error message I see when using a tuple for `chunkshape`, 'ValueError: chunkshape rank (length) must be 1: (23, 1)'.

Comment: I think this is due to the fact that you either didn't specify a shape or specified it something like (10000,) instead of (10000,20). 
You can check the shape by printing the `dataset.shape` property.

Comment: I'm confused.  I passed chunkshape as (23,1) when creating the table.  So how can I set the shape on a dataset before it has been created?  I don't see any other way to set the shape when creating the table.

Comment: you are right, you can't specify the shape when you create the table. How do you write data to the table? Do you pass a numpy array? can you still check the shape property of your table and check what it is set to?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16883/discussion-between-durden2-0-and-umit)